# Java Sudoku Recursive Solver

Tags: java

I am very confused why I am still getting these errors. I have commented in the code what is giving me the errors. Any advice would be great.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SudokuSolver  {

    private static int[][] grid;
    int r, c;
    public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


        try {
            System.out.println("Enter File name: ");
            Scanner fin = new Scanner (System.in);
            String fname = fin.next();
            fin = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fname));
            int [][] board = new int [9][9];
            for (int r = 0; r<9; r++) {
                for (int c=0; c<9; c++) {
                    board [r][c] = fin.nextInt();
                }
            }
            for (int r = 0; r < 9; r++) {
                for(int c = 0; c < 9; c++) {
                    System.out.print(board[r][c]);
                }
            }
            if(solveSudoku(grid == true)) //giving an error "Incompatible Operand Types" 
                printGrid(grid);
            else 
                System.out.printf("No solution exists");

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File could not be found. Exiting...");
            System.exit(0);

        }
    }
    public boolean solveSudoku(int[][] grid) {
        if(!findUnassignedLocation(grid)) {
            return true;
        for (int num = 1; num <= 9; num++) {
            if(isValid(grid,r,c,digit)) //Throwing error "digit can not be resolved as a variable"
            {
                grid[r][c] = num;
                if(solveSudoku(grid))
                    return true;

                grid[r][c] = 0;
            }
            return false; 
        }

        }
    }
    public boolean findUnassignedLocation(int[][] grid) {
        for(r = 0; r < 9; r++) {
            for(c= 0; c < 9; c++) {
                if(grid[r][c]==0)
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public boolean inRow(int[][] grid, int r, int digit) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 9; c++) {
            if(grid[r][c] == digit)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public boolean inCol(int[][] grid, int c, int digit) {
        for(int r = 0; r < 9; r++ ) {
            if(grid[r][c] == digit)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public boolean inBox(int[][] grid, int startR, int startC, int digit) {
        for (int r = 0; r <3; r++) 
            for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
                if(grid[r+startR][c+startC] == digit)
                    return true;
        return false; 

    }
    public boolean isValid(int[][] grid, int r, int c, int digit) {
        return !inRow(grid,r,digit) && !inCol(grid,c,digit) && !inBox(grid,r-r%3,c-c%3,digit);
    }

    static void printGrid(int[][] grid) {
        for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
        {
           for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
                 System.out.printf("%2d", grid[row][col]);
            System.out.printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your error.

Comment: `if(solveSudoku(grid == true))` Did you mean `if(solveSudoku(grid) == true)`?

Comment: And unsurprisingly, `digit can not be resolved as a variable` means that `digit` cannot be resolved as a variable.

Comment: And the error in `solveSudoku(int[][] grid)` , `if(isValid(grid,r,c,digit))` the variable digit doesn't exist in that scope, either you forgot to add it as an argument to the function or forgot to declare and initialize it in that function.

Comment: Alec, I am very beginner so I am sorry if I sound ignorant. But how would i go about doing that?

Comment: So you should either be calling solveSudoku with digit as a parameter so `solveSudoku(int [][] grid, int digit)` and then create the digit variable to call the function with or at the begining of solveSudoku create the digit variable.

Comment: if(isValid(grid,r,c,digit)) perhaps what you really want is  if(isValid(grid,r,c,num))?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if(solveSudoku(grid == true)) //giving an error "Incompatible Operand Types"

if(isValid(grid,r,c,digit)) //Throwing error "digit can not be resolved as a variable"
```

To:

```
if(solveSudoku(grid))

if(isValid(grid,r,c,num))
```